# HTTP request with web auth and port

Tags: php, http, curl, basic-authentication

I need to perform a request to the following URL:

http://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@[SERVER_IP]:[PORT]/some/path/to/some/file

BUT the finally generated URL is treated as INVALID because it contains the ':' character twice.
Is there any solution?

That is what I tried:

```
$process = curl_init('http://[SERVER_IP]:[PORT]/OpenKM/webdav/okm:personal/somefile.mp4');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]");
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($process);  // $return is FALSE
var_dump(curl_error($process));die();  // Here we see string(23) "Empty reply from server"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put encoded value of ':' instead, **%3A**

I suggest you to user URL Encoder tools widely available online, check one of them here...

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Also here is complete char encoding list provided by w3school...

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: which of the two colons should be encoded? The links posted do not serve to convince me this is the correct answer.

Comment: I tried "[USERNAME]%3A[PASSWORD]" and even "okm%3Apersonal" instead of "okm:personal" but it did not help. Was that what you mean?

Comment: @JanDvorak check example given here in PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php  

I hope it serves your purpose

Comment: @BogdanBurim no, only the second part, after the port onwards.

Comment: Trying out.. Response is big and SOMETHING seems to load... I will report in soon about the result.

Comment: That helped. Thanks very much to everyone who helped me to find a solution. I hope other people will find this question usefull.